# Is it possible to have the filename and cursor position displayed continuously -- WITHOUT using statusline?

Tags: vimrc

Typing ^G gives

`"filename" 119 lines --17%--                              21,0-1        Top`

Setting `statusline=%t\ %m%r%50l,%c%V\ %P` gives e.g.:

```
filename [+]                            21, 0-1       Top
-- INSERT --
```

i.e. the statusline is *in addition* to the normal line used for :ex cmds, showmode and ruler.

Ideally, I'd like something like:

```
filename [+]       -- INSERT --                          21, 0-1       Top
```

as the line normally used by the ruler. I.e. not using a statusline (and not the window title either).

Comment: ruler might be it?

Comment: @MaximKim I seem to recall rulerfmt that might do it if the filename can be included.

Comment: Yes, `:set rulerformat=%t\ %m%r\ %l,%c%V\ %P` is more or less what I want. It gives `-- INSERT --              tst.c [+] 5,1 All` (in insert-mode, with showmode set).

Comment: I've changed this to`:set rulerformat=%50(%t\ %m%r\ %l,%c%V\ %P%)` because the output gets truncated if the output is too long. The change means the output is no longer right-justified :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[neovim](/questions/tagged/neovim)

I believe in neovim you would do this with `:set cmdheight=0` so that the statusline occupies the bottom of the window. There is a side-effect that opening a command line with `:` shifts the display a bit, IIRC.

[vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

I think the closest thing in Vim is the ruler. You could make this show what you want with `rulerformat`.

Comment: Thanks, rulerformat does the trick (and no, cmdheight=0 doesn't work in vim).